# Lubuntu - What is the BEST (and most of all easiest) way to monitor as well as block websites?

Tags: lubuntu, security, firewall, privacy

I set up an older Dell laptop for our kids to play with as well as use for school projects.  However, just like with any technology they poke around and do what they want when no one is over their shoulder watching them.
I routinely walk into the kitchen (where they use the computer) and instantly there is a shuffle to change what is on the screen... so what were they doing?
I usually wait until they are gone and check the history.  Every single time it shows something that they are not suppose to be doing... whether it be a website they shouldn't be on - because they said they were doing school work - or there is a large gap of time between activity.

So last night they told one of them told their mom they needed to do a school project.  We had a party to attend and left around 7:15PM... she had gotten on around 7PM.  If you can see the history... mere minutes after we left she had stopped doing anything on the web - where she had to go to do the project - and there was a gap of time until 10:09PM, where she got on to a movie site.  Now to clarify... I have the computers go to sleep so that a password needs o be entered, which means there was still activity on the computer between 7:25PM until 10:09PM to keep it from suspending... doing what?  Is there a way for me to tell? ... I was assuming I needed some kind of tracker program or script to be installed.
The reason this irritates me is they think they are smarter than their mother and talk to her like the did nothing, yet we can see they were not doing what they were suppose to be doing?!?

... thank you!
[browsing_history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP6Gn.png)

Comment: I guess this is more of parenting type of question than a Ubuntu Question. But here goes. I'm a parent myself. I have some knowledge how to track browser and how to block sites on the router. Still, I won't bother. 1. Let's say it's 100% of the"bad" sites are blocked. They call still go the neighbor watch it from there. 2. I don't want to raise them telling them having no online privacy is okay (it is not, let's say the government were to follow your every step. Would that be okay?) 3. I don't want to nanny them with every step they take.

Comment: So what I **do** is watch my kids over their shoulder ever now and then and ask them if those things were okay to watch and what it made feel them. If necessary I add my own view.

Comment: all true... I don't necessarily want to block them from going to the sites that they can go to, just hate when they sit there and lie to your face about what they were doing ... when you could clearly see what they were doing?!?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this. But maybe you should *not* check their browser history as afterwards you will have to confess to your kids that you have (somewhat) invaded their privacy and have less moral standing ground when you want to act upon it.

Comment: There is a question about this topic: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/should-i-monitor-my-childs-internet-usage